# How to debug QEMU under Xen?

Tags: debugging, qemu

I am running a Xen server and I would like to debug the QEMU process. However, I don't want to run the QEMU process standalone, but I want it to run to back my domU.

How can I run and debug QEMU in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This answer describes two possible approaches. Hope somebody else can share more ways to do it.

Preliminary note: to have a debug-friendly build of QEMU, use the `--enable-debug` config option.

Debugging QEMU under Xen is a bit peculiar because of the integration between the hypervisor and QEMU. If you don't want to run QEMU standalone (no acceleration), the only choice under Xen is to use Xen as accelerator, as KVM will not work.

To do so, I don't think it's possible to manually run QEMU from the command line, but you have to let Xen start the process when the domU is launched. You can then use one of the following two options:

1. start your VM via Xen (`xl create ...`), then use `gdb` via command line attaching it to the QEMU process that Xen has started;
2. change `device_model_override` in the Xen configuration of the VM to point to a script that contains something like `exec gdbserver :1234 /path/to/qemu $@` - then you can start the VM like above (via Xen) and use `target remote :123`" in `gdb` to attach to the debugging session.

Option number 2 is particularly useful when looking at a crash that happens early in the startup if `xl create -p ...` doesn't help because it crashes whether the Xen VM is running or paused. It is also useful if you want to pass extra environment variables to QEMU. This is sometimes also useful in debugging.

Your script could look like the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
QEMU_LOG=/var/log/xen/qemu-log-debug.log   # custom log file
export SSLKEYLOGFILE=/tmp/qemu-debug-ssl-key.log    # extra env vars
export GNUTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL=4                         # extra env vars
export XEN_QEMU_CONSOLE_LIMIT=0                     # extra env vars
exec gdbserver 0.0.0.0:1234 /path/to/qemu-xen/qemu-system-i386 $@ &> "$QEMU_LOG"
```